# Writing SQL to develop XML with children

Tags: sql, xml, parent-child, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to write SQL to generate an XML string complete with child elements. I can get everything, but the children aren't falling as children, they are showing as separate root level items. I've been dinking around with the XML path statement, but just am not having any luck.

Help would be appreciated. I'm on a SQL 2014 server.

```
declare @xmldata xml
set     @xmldata = (    SELECT adr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER   
                            , adr.FIRST_NAME
                            , adr.LAST_NAME
                            , adr.ADDR_LINE1
                            , adr.ADDR_LINE2
                            , adr.CITY
                            , adr.STATE
                            , adr.ZIP
                            , ( SELECT ACCT_NBR
                                    , LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT
                                    , LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT
                                    , LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT 
                                FROM Staging.StatementOfBalance_SRC sob
                                WHERE  sob.ACCT_NBR = crbr.ACCT_NBR 
                                FOR XML path('accounts'), TYPE, elements )
                        from Staging.Account_Data crbr
                        join Unit_Cost.ADDRESSES_ALL adr on crbr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER = adr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER    
                        FOR XML path('letter'), root ('statement'), elements    )

SELECT @xmldata as returnXML
```

My results are

```
<statement>
    <letter>
        <ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>123321</ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>
        <FIRST_NAME>Pippi</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Longstockings</LAST_NAME>
        <ADDR_LINE1>123 Out Onna Boat</ADDR_LINE1>
        <ADDR_LINE2 />
        <CITY>Ocean</CITY>
        <STATE>ME</STATE>
        <ZIP>000000</ZIP>
        <accounts>
            <ACCT_NBR>0000000000000000</ACCT_NBR>
            <LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>2670.00</LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>
            <LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>2749.09</LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>
            <LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>4.75000</LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>
        </accounts>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>123321</ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>
        <FIRST_NAME>Pippi</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Longstockings</LAST_NAME>
        <ADDR_LINE1>123 Out Onna Boat</ADDR_LINE1>
        <ADDR_LINE2 />
        <CITY>Ocean</CITY>
        <STATE>ME</STATE>
        <ZIP>000000</ZIP>
        <accounts>
            <ACCT_NBR>0000000000000000</ACCT_NBR>
            <LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>4082.00</LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>
            <LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>5520.21</LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>
            <LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>5.50000</LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>
        </accounts>
    </letter>
</statement>
```

but what I need is:

```
 <statement>
        <letter>
            <ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>123321</ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>
            <FIRST_NAME>Pippi</FIRST_NAME>
            <LAST_NAME>Longstockings</LAST_NAME>
            <ADDR_LINE1>123 Out Onna Boat</ADDR_LINE1>
            <ADDR_LINE2 />
            <CITY>Ocean</CITY>
            <STATE>ME</STATE>
            <ZIP>000000</ZIP>
            <accounts>
                <ACCT_NBR>0000000000000000</ACCT_NBR>
                <LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>2670.00</LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>
                <LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>2749.09</LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>
                <LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>4.75000</LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>
            </accounts>
            <accounts>
                <ACCT_NBR>0000000000000000</ACCT_NBR>
                <LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>4082.00</LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>
                <LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>5520.21</LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT>
                <LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>5.50000</LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT>
            </accounts>
        </letter>
    </statement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is your join in the outer SELECT... You did not provide your structure, nor did you provide sample data...

Your actual output doubles the master row while you want - at least the expected output points to this - an 1:n relation between letter and account.

I tried to simplify your query and declared tables fitting to the query, but took away the joined table and the output seems to be OK:

```
DECLARE @letter TABLE(ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER INT,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100),LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @letter VALUES(123321,'Pippi','Longstockings');
DECLARE @account TABLE(ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER INT,ACCT_NBR VARCHAR(100), LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT DECIMAL (14,4));
INSERT INTO @account VALUES(123321,'00000000000',2670.00),(123321,'00000000000',4082.00);

SELECT 
      adr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER   
    , adr.FIRST_NAME
    , adr.LAST_NAME
    --, adr.ADDR_LINE1
    --, adr.ADDR_LINE2
    --, adr.CITY
    --, adr.STATE
    --, adr.ZIP
    , ( SELECT ACCT_NBR
            , LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT
            --, LOAN_OSTD_PRIN_AMT
            --, LOAN_EFTV_INT_RT 
        FROM @account sob -- Staging.StatementOfBalance_SRC sob
        WHERE  sob.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER = adr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER-- crbr.ACCT_NBR 
        FOR XML path('accounts'), TYPE, elements )
from @letter adr --Staging.Account_Data crbr
                 --join Unit_Cost.ADDRESSES_ALL adr on crbr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER = adr.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER    
FOR XML path('letter'), root ('statement')
```

The result

```
<statement>
  <letter>
    <ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>123321</ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>
    <FIRST_NAME>Pippi</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Longstockings</LAST_NAME>
    <accounts>
      <ACCT_NBR>00000000000</ACCT_NBR>
      <LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>2670.0000</LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>
    </accounts>
    <accounts>
      <ACCT_NBR>00000000000</ACCT_NBR>
      <LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>4082.0000</LOAN_ORGL_PRIN_AMT>
    </accounts>
  </letter>
</statement>
```

So my advise:

Test this **without `FOR XML PATH`** and go from outside to the inside. First you should be happy with

```
<statement>
  <letter>
    <ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>123321</ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER>
    <FIRST_NAME>Pippi</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Longstockings</LAST_NAME>
    --more columns
  </letter>
</statement>
```

When this works, you define your sub-select to add the appropriate accounts. Your query looks quite OK acutally, so I suspect the reason in your table's relations which do not result the way you expect it...

Comment: Thanks Shnugo! I had the WHERE in the inside select using the account numbers, and not the account identifier. Matching your change made it work. Happy Monday :)

Comment: WOOT! yeah, I was going to say ... I'm not at the magical spot ... voted UP!